# Extract shapes from google maps or place api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I would like to get the shape of some postcodes. Google maps provides this on the web interface, but I cannot seem to find it in an API.

For example:

https://www.google.de/maps/place/10407+Berlin/@52.5343684,13.445555,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47a84e74c0c46115:0x1c212049953dce70

We have the boundaries of the postcode 10407 in Germany. Is there a way to get the points?

Comment: Not from a Google API (at least at present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FusionTable with polygons of german postcode-areas: 
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1fWU5Hb7_inrUsijiGbyH8d-TLq7jKs7LCnrb_Ao#map:id=3

path for [10407](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1fWU5Hb7_inrUsijiGbyH8d-TLq7jKs7LCnrb_Ao#map:id=18):

```
 [
  [52.538261, 13.450629], 
  [52.539188, 13.449742], 
  [52.542725, 13.440916], 
  [52.538097, 13.435909], 
  [52.53043, 13.42698], 
  [52.530327, 13.427414], 
  [52.530933, 13.432997], 
  [52.530247, 13.436489], 
  [52.5312, 13.440932], 
  [52.53022, 13.442185], 
  [52.527954, 13.444298], 
  [52.528072, 13.444825], 
  [52.529335, 13.449499], 
  [52.528686, 13.450039], 
  [52.530598, 13.458764], 
  [52.530556, 13.458761], 
  [52.531242, 13.46181], 
  [52.531891, 13.464031], 
  [52.539566, 13.469425], 
  [52.542442, 13.462722], 
  [52.543388, 13.45931], 
  [52.543613, 13.458677]
 ]
```

More accurate data you should get(of course not for free) from [Deutsche Post Datafactory](https://www.deutschepost.de/de/d/deutsche-post-direkt/datafactory.html) (Geocode)